# Djoser, does not send email, I do not know what else to do

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, djoser

I am making a base project to send emails with djoser, but I am not receiving any confirmation email

-I have two-step verification enabled on your main Gmail account.
-I have generated a password for the application.

This is my configuration settings.

setting.py

```
# Simple_JWT settings
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    "AUTH_HEADER_TYPES": ("JWT",),
    "ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(minutes=60),
    "REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=1),
    "ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS": True,
    "UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN": True,
}

# Email settings
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get("EMAIL_HOST_USER")
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD")
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

# Djoser settings
Djoser = {
    "LOGIN_FIELD": "email",
    "USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE": True,
    "ACTIVATION_URL": "/activate/{uid}/{token}",
    "SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL": True,
    "SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL": True,
    "PASSWORD_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION": True,
    "PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL": "/password-reset/{uid}/{token}",
    "SET_PASSWORD_RETYPE": True,
    "PASSWORD_RESET_SHOW_EMAIL_NOT_FOUND": True,
    "TOKEN_MODEL": None,
    "SERIALIZERS": {
        
        "user_create": "accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer",
        "user": "accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer",
        "user_delete": "djoser.serializers.UserDeleteSerializer",
    },
    "EMAIL": {
        "activation": "accounts.email.ActivationEmail",
        "confirmation": "accounts.email.ConfirmationEmail",
        "password_reset": "accounts.email.PasswordResetEmail",
        "password_changed_confirmation": "accounts.email.PasswordChangedConfirmationEmail",
    },
}
```

When I register it accepts my request but does not send anything

```
14/Mar/2024 09:38:53] "POST /api/auth/users/ HTTP/1.1" 201 103
```

How could I solve this proble